# Implementing OWIN Database Context for ASP.NET Application Database First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext, owin

The book I'm reading says that I should use OWIN to get an instance of my database context for using Identity... but I'm using database first so I want to have an instance of my database context for use throughout my application.

I've implemented the 'Start' class for OWIN in the following way:

```
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using uQuiz.Domain;
using uQuiz.Domain.Concrete;
using uQuiz.WebUI.Infrastructure;

namespace uQuiz
{
    public class OwinStart
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Configures OWIN
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<QuizEntities>(GetQuizEntities);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an instance of the QuizEntities database context for OWIN
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static QuizEntities GetQuizEntities()
        {
            return new QuizEntities();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a function there that just produces a single instance of my database context `QuizEntities`, which is database first so automatically generated.

I know that it is normal practice to have a 'Create' method within your database context, but I can't do this because it is automatically generated.

**My Questions:**

- Is there a down side of creating an instance 'per OWIN' in this way?
- Is this an acceptable way of implementing it?
- Is it acceptable to use the same database context for Identity and other requests within the application?

Comment: It's not OPINION BASED I'm asking for the best practice for the situation, which is using OWIN but getting an instance of my database for database first (not code first) and using it for Identity Framework and for other requests.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a database context per OWIN context, not per OWIN. It's not a single instance. For each incoming request, a database context is created. So OWIN calls `GetQuizEntities` for each request to create a new database context.

> Is there a down side of creating an instance 'per OWIN' in this way?

No, you must do it the way you are doing now, otherwise your db context will get bloated. Create a new db context per request. Right.

> Is this an acceptable way of implementing it?

Yes it is.

> Is it acceptable to use the same database context for Identity and other requests within the application?

I'm not sure what you mean there.

Comment: Thank you for answering :).  With regard to the third question, I am using the same database context for Identity Framework and other Entity Framework requests.  I just wanted to know that it is OK to use the same database context for Identity Framework and for general Entity Framework requests.

Comment: It's totally OK. The only downside of DbContext is that it stores any object fetched from database in memory. So if you use a single db context for a lot of queries, it gets slower and consumes a lot of memory. That's why we create a db context per request.